# How to make a secure login page over SSL HTTPS?

Tags: ajax, forms, security, ssl, https

I was trying to figure out how to submit a login form securely. I went through many discussions and topics on Google and Stack Overflow, read many things about hashing passwords, making secure sessions, making secure cookies and so on and on, but 1 solution seems to be the easiest and the most secured solution and that would be SSL HTTPS, so I have activated the SSL on my dedicated server, but I am not sure about how to have my form to submit over HTTPS?

Someone told me that, I don't need to do any complicated coding, I will just need to use

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]   
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^yourdomain.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect all the pages over https and then just simply submit my forms through form action and post method, and I should not even use AJAX to submit the form.

But, this sounds too simple to me, so I thought about writing my thought here and ask the professionals about it.

So here is the question: will the above code secure all the submissions? Should I add any more coding like hashing and slat to submit the form over https?  I need to secure my login register forms.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think when you access a https link, your browser will perform some handshake exchanging some data to create an encrypted channel, and only after that it will transfer the form data.

Comment: but of course, there are several security risks on everything...

Comment: @Leo ummm.... no one is pretty sure about the SSL :) but there are many topics out there saying SSL is the safest, I am pretty confused here.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @Leo thanks for the reference, it is very useful to me, and I would be grateful if you could vote up the question, really appreciated

Comment: sure, why not upvote it. it's a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the best link I know about what you want to learn

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet

good luck